# Websphere MQ Explorer & AMQ8077 Errors

Tags: ibm-mq

I see a bunch of errors that looks like

```
AMQ8077: Entity 'tcs-mq-user ' has insufficient authority to access object 'SYSTEM.INTERNAL.REPLY.QUEUE'
```

on the mq error logs whenever I access the queue objects via MQ Explorer. This is repeated for many system objects such as....

```
 SYSTEM.MQEXPLORER.REPLY.MODEL SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.QUEUE
 SYSTEM.SELECTION.VALIDATION.QUEUE SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE
 SYSTEM.RETAINED.PUB.QUEUE SYSTEM.PENDING.DATA.QUEUE
 SYSTEM.NDURABLE.MODEL.QUEUE SYSTEM.MQSC.REPLY.QUEUE
 SYSTEM.JMS.TEMPQ.MODEL SYSTEM.INTERNAL.REPLY.QUEUE
 SYSTEM.INTER.QMGR.PUBS SYSTEM.INTER.QMGR.FANREQ
 SYSTEM.INTER.QMGR.CONTROL SYSTEM.HIERARCHY.STATE
 SYSTEM.DURABLE.SUBSCRIBER.QUEUE SYSTEM.DURABLE.MODEL.QUEUE
 SYSTEM.DOTNET.XARECOVERY.QUEUE SYSTEM.DEFAULT.REMOTE.QUEUE
 SYSTEM.DEFAULT.MODEL.QUEUE SYSTEM.DEFAULT.LOCAL.QUEUE
 SYSTEM.DEFAULT.INITIATION.QUEUE SYSTEM.DEFAULT.ALIAS.QUEUE
 SYSTEM.DEAD.LETTER.QUEUE SYSTEM.CLUSTER.TRANSMIT.QUEUE
 SYSTEM.CLUSTER.REPOSITORY.QUEUE SYSTEM.CLUSTER.REPOSITORY.QUEUE
 SYSTEM.CLUSTER.HISTORY.QUEUE SYSTEM.CLUSTER.COMMAND.QUEUE
 SYSTEM.CICS.INITIATION.QUEUE SYSTEM.CICS.INITIATION.QUEUE
```

How do I get rid of these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When WMQ Explorer paints the queues screen, it needs to enumerate all the queues and does so by issuing the command server equivalent of `DIS Q(*)` as a PCF command.  The results of that command are returned on a per-queue basis so each queue the user has access to display returns `MQCC=0` whereas each queue the user has no access to display returns `MQCC=2, MQRC=2035`.  Since it does this for each queue hat is defined, you will need to authorize `tcs-mq-user` to at least display all queues.

Since `tcs-user` is in the `mq-user` group (based on notes in previous postings) then do this:

```
SET AUTHREC PROFILE('**') GROUP('mq-users') OBJTYPE(QUEUE) AUTHADD(DSP)
```

Note that you need **two** asterisks in the profile name because WMQ recognizes dot characters as node separators.  For example, using a profile of `SYSTEM*` would match a queue named `SYSTEM_QUEUE` but not one named `SYSTEM.QUEUE` because the single asterisk wildcard matches only a single node in the name.  A two-asterisk wildcard like `SYSTEM**` would match both names.  To match all `SYSTEM` queues, you usually would use the pattern `SYSTEM.**`, including the dot and both asterisks.  That way the pattern excludes user-defined names like `SYSTEMIC`  but matches all the default object names.  To match all queues, just use the pattern `**` as shown in the command example above.

You will also get many of the same errors on the other objects.  To get around all of these in one step, first apply the base authorizations as explained in the post on [Viewing Channels in WebSphere MQ Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799377/websphere-mq-viewing-channels-in-wmq-explorer/11799762#11799762).  That gives the ability to display and/or inquire on all objects, then you can add more specific profiles to allow put, get, browse, etc. on just the objects where `mq-user` requires more access.

You may also want to have a look at the [WebSphere MQ Security Heats](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0711_col_wyatt/0711_col_wyatt.html) Up article on developerWorks for more background and setmqaut commands.